# Why to use FormBuilder instead of FormGroup?

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms

```
While creating a reactive forms in angular we why we need to use formBuilder instead of FormGroup when we can make reactive forms using either of them.
Here i also provided what i am trying to ask 

maintenanceForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
 this.maintenanceForm = new FormGroup({
      'value': new FormControl(null),
      'dropdown': new FormControl(null)
    })
}
```

/* Here As we can make reactive forms in this two ways but when to use either of them  */

```
this.maintenanceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        body_type_id: ['', Validators.required],
        make_name: ['', Validators.required]
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Form my experience, using FormBuilder reduces the syntax to be written especially when you have very large and complex forms. Please see below links,

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

This link shows the syntactic difference between using both approaches
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms